# change the date on the datetimepicker when clicking

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am trying to display the date of the existing data, then I want to display the date when I click the input text and display the date I set but did not work how?

```
<input type="text" name="start"  id="start_date"  value="2017-12-05"/>

$('#start_date').datetimepicker({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
});

 $('#start_date').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function (e) {
     var dt = "2017-12-12"
     $('#start_date').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(incrementDay);
  });
```

so when I want to select a new date date minDate on 2017-12-12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to use date format inside the `minDate` method. May it help.

```js
var incrementDay = 7;
$('#start_date').datetimepicker({
  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
});
$('#start_date').one('click',function(){
var start_date = $('#start_date').data('DateTimePicker'); 
var stDate = new Date(start_date.date());
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setDate(stDate.getDate() + incrementDay)
start_date.minDate(newDate);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: relative">
  <input type="text" name="start" id="start_date" value="2017-12-05" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @RonyLoud, not running, so I expect when I click on the date before the date 2017-12-12

Comment: Can you please make it little bit clear what u wanna achieve.

Comment: so the default date when appearing is 2017-12-05, after I click its text input the date shows 2017-12-12 as the minDate

Comment: Please check the Updated answer. May it meet your requirement